# Livewire algorithm (intelligent scissors) step by step

Tags: image, algorithm, image-processing

I'm trying to code the livewire algorithm but I'm a little stuck because the algorithm explained in the article "Intelligent Scissors for Image Composition" is a little messy and I don't understand complety how to apply certain things for example: How to calculate de local cost map and other stuff.

So please can anyone give a hand and explain it step by step in just simple words?

I would apreciate any help

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should read [Mortensen, Eric N., and William A. Barrett. "Interactive segmentation with intelligent scissors." Graphical models and image processing 60.5 (1998): 349-384.](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.89.2987&rep=rep1&type=pdf) which contains more details about the algorithm than the shorter paper "Intelligent Scissors for Image Composition."

Here is a high-level overview:

The Intelligent Scissors algorithm uses a variant of Dijkstra's graph search algorithm to find a minimum cost path from a seed pixel to a destination pixel (the position of the mouse cursor during interactive segmentation).

**1) Local costs**

Each edge from a pixel `p` to a pixel `q` has a local cost, which is a linear combination of the local costs (adjusted by the distance between `p` and `q` to account for diagonal pixels):

- Laplacian zero-crossing `f_Z(q)`
- Gradient magnitude `f_G(q)`
- Gradient direction `f_D(p,q)`
- Edge pixel value `f_P(q)`
- Inside pixel value `f_I(q)`
- Outside pixel value `f_O(q)`

Some of these local costs are static and can be computed offline. `f_Z` and `f_G` are computed at different scales (meaning with different size kernels) to better represent the edge a pixel `q`. `f_G`, `f_P`, `f_I`, `f_O` are dynamically (or have a dynamic component as is the case for `f_G`) computed for on-the-fly training.

**2) On-the-fly training**

To prevent snapping to a different edge with a lower cost than the current one being followed, the algorithm uses on-the-fly training to assign a lower cost to neighboring pixels that "look like" past pixels along the current edge.

This is done by building a histogram of image value features along the last 64 or 128 edge pixels. The image value features are computed by scaling and rounding `f'_G` (where `f_G = 1 - f'_G`), `f_P`, `f_I`, and `f_O` as to have integer values in `[0 255]` or `[0 1023]` which can be used to index the histograms.

The histograms are inverted and scaled to compute dynamic cost maps `m_G`, `m_P`, `m_I`, and `m_O`. The idea is that a low cost neighbor `q` should fit in the histogram of the 64 or 128 pixels previously seen.

The paper gives pseudo code showing how to compute these dynamic costs given a list of previously chosen pixels on the path.

**3) Graph search**

The static and dynamic costs are combined together into a single cost to move from pixel `p` to one of its 8 neighbors `q`. Finding the lowest cost path from a seed pixel to a destination pixel is done by essentially using Dijkstra's algorithm with a min-priority queue. The paper gives pseudo code.

Comment: Thanks for the reply I will try to apply it, any doubt can I ask you again?